# Django - ImportError: No module named djangochat.settings

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

Here is my error trace of `python manage.py runserver` I am using **django 1.10.7** with **python 2.7**

```
(faavenv) user@ubutnu:~/Documents/faa-backend$ python manage.py runserver
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 14, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/user/Documents/faa-backend/faavenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 367, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/user/Documents/faa-backend/faavenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 316, in execute
    settings.INSTALLED_APPS
  File "/home/user/Documents/faa-backend/faavenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 53, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/home/user/Documents/faa-backend/faavenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 41, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "/home/user/Documents/faa-backend/faavenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 97, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
ImportError: No module named djangochat.settings
```

Here is my requirements.txt

```
amqp==2.2.1
anyjson==0.3.3
asn1crypto==0.22.0
Babel==2.4.0
backports-abc==0.5
bcrypt==3.1.3
BeautifulSoup==3.2.1
beautifulsoup4==4.6.0
billiard==3.5.0.3
bleach==2.0.0
boto==2.48.0
boto3==1.4.4
botocore==1.5.80
celery==4.1.0
certifi==2017.4.17
cffi==1.10.0
chardet==3.0.4
cryptography==1.9
Django==1.10.7
django-celery-beat==1.0.1
django-contrib-comments==1.8.0
django-debug-toolbar==1.8
django-environ==0.4.3
django-nocaptcha-recaptcha==0.0.19
django-storages-redux==1.3.3
docutils==0.13.1
enum34==1.1.6
Fabric==1.13.2
feedparser==5.2.1
filebrowser-safe==0.4.7
flower==0.9.2
future==0.16.0
futures==3.1.1
grappelli-safe==0.4.6
html5lib==0.999999999
idna==2.5
ipaddress==1.0.18
jmespath==0.9.3
kombu==4.1.0
Mezzanine==4.2.3
nltk==3.2.4
numpy==1.13.0
oauthlib==2.0.2
olefile==0.44
pandas==0.20.2
paramiko==2.2.1
Pillow==4.1.1
psycopg2==2.7.1
pyasn1==0.2.3
pycparser==2.17
pycryptodomex==3.4.6
pyjwkest==1.3.6
PyJWT==1.5.2
PyNaCl==1.1.2
python-dateutil==2.6.0
python-openid==2.2.5
pytz==2017.2
requests==2.18.1
requests-oauthlib==0.8.0
s3transfer==0.1.10
scikit-learn==0.18.2
scipy==0.19.1
singledispatch==3.4.0.3
six==1.10.0
sklearn==0.0
social-auth-app-django==1.2.0
social-auth-core==1.4.0
sqlparse==0.2.3
tornado==4.5.1
tzlocal==1.4
urllib3==1.21.1
vine==1.1.4
webencodings==0.5.1
```

Problem is that I haven't install Django chat in my environment. Still, it is showing above error. Not only this project but in all project, I am receiving this error.

I tried to reinstall all library again but doesn't help.

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

```
(faavenv) user@ubuntu:~/Documents/faa-backend$ python manage.py shell
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 14, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/user/Documents/faa-backend/faavenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 367, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/user/Documents/faa-backend/faavenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 316, in execute
    settings.INSTALLED_APPS
  File "/home/user/Documents/faa-backend/faavenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 53, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/home/user/Documents/faa-backend/faavenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 41, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "/home/soham/Documents/faa-backend/faavenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 97, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
ImportError: No module named djangochat.settings


(faavenv) user@ubuntu:~/Documents/faa-backend$ python
Python 2.7.12 (default, Nov 19 2016, 06:48:10) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import djangoChat
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named djangoChat
>>>
```

Comment: What do you get if you run `manage.py shell` and try to `import djangoChat`?

Comment: @Haranadh I have updated my question with the output of a command that you suggested.

Comment: is your settings file in the directory djangochat? does the directory exists?

Comment: @BearBrown No, There is no any Django chat directory in my project. I am not using in my project.

Answer (score 0):

This error usually happens because you have a file that uses django and django is not imported.

You probably have a script somewhere in your project that is imported and has a executable function without the `if __name__ == "__main__":` part. So runserver imports this script, try to execute and fail, because django is not imported. So, if you have something like this, be sure that the running function is inside the above if statement, so runserver does not try to run the script when it is imported.

So, if you want to run a script that uses django (and it is not inside the models, views, forms usual stuff), you need to setup django first. You need to find the problematic file and add the following at the top:

```
import django 
sys.path.append("path/to/django/settingsapp")
os.environ["DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE"] = "djangochat.settings"
django.setup()
```

If you find the problematic file and add the above, it will probably fix it.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for all answers, I just moved my project location and set it up again and It works. still, I don't know what was the issue but after moving project directory and environment It is working.